# Outputting WordPress shortcode with custom function, not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

Have used the following function countless times to output raw text wrapped in the relevant HTML tags. But all of a sudden, not working?!?

It's outputting raw text (ie; airbush-line) which I know is basically what do_shortcode will echo. Just that it is no longer running through my custom function?

I have a custom meta field in a CPT, which output raw text, which I would then wrap in my function, so an icon would be displayed, but it's currently not playing ball?

The meta box code -

```
$prefix = 'theme_';

$meta_box_service = array(
'id' => 'service_details',
'title' => __( 'Service Details', 'budd' ),
'page' => 'services',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => __( 'Service Icon', 'budd' ),
        'id' => $prefix . 'service_icon',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'Airbush (Line)' => 'airbrush-line',
            'Airbrush (Solid)' => 'airbrush-solid',
            'Bar Chart (Solid)' => 'bar-chart-solid'

        )
    ),
    array(
       'name' => __( 'Service URL', 'budd' ),
       'id' => $prefix . 'service_url',
       'type' => 'text',
       'std' => ''
    )
)
);

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_add_box_service' );
```

The do_shortcode for the front-end -

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'theme_service_icon', $single = true ) ) ?>
```

And the function I have already -

```
class IconsMind {
public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'init' ) );
}

public function init() {
    add_shortcode( 'icon', array( $this, 'setup_shortcode' ) );
    add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
}

public function setup_shortcode( $params ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'name'  => 'icon-airbush-line'
            ), $params ) );
    $icon = '<i class="'.$params['name'].'"></i>';

    return $icon;
}

}

new IconsMind();
```

Any advice, truly appreciated

thanks